# How to integrate solidjs and django

Tags: django, solid-js

I want to set up a web application which in backend uses django and in front end uses solidjs. In the development phase how do I integrate solidjs into django?

I have a directory called project which contains directory called:

- back (django-admin startproject back)
- front (npx degit solidjs/templates/ts front)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but you'd simply run django and solidjs separately, and use API calls to communicate between them (so you won't be using django's template system).

Comment: hello, how i do for crsf token ?

Answer (score 2):

During development phase you can create a proxy config in your vite configuration file that makes API call to your django server:

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy

For production, link the js file that has your solid app in your html file or html template you return from your server.